# "Map 1" vs "Map 0"

Tags: qgis

When I compose a map to print, and get everything all set; then close it for some reason; then reopen it--the scale bar appears messed up. I then go to the Scale Bar settings, and find that under "Map" there is more than one option. Changing that fixes the scale bar. How can I fix this permanently? I don't even know what this other "map" refers to. I did not intentionally add it to my map. How can I delete the "Map" that is messing things up?
THANKS
-TVZ
(Using QGIS 1.8.0, Windows 7)

Comment: I think this was a bug and has been fixed.  Could you try a nightly build?

Comment: Thanks Nathan. Is trying a nightly build one of those things that they warn you about, that may mess things up? I'm not very geeky, and would rather live w/ this than create some complication. Would you recommend it for someone like me? And if so, please advise where to go to do this.

Thanks very much.

Comment: You can run 1.8 and the nighly side by side (on windows anyway).  So you can always install it just to test if a bug has been fixed